# Word for someone who thinks very highly of themselves but is not self-centered, self-righteous, narcissistic, egocentric, etc

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word to describe someone who thinks very highly of themselves but is not self-centered, self-righteous, narcissistic, egocentric, etc?

Comment: It might help if you included a sample sentence where the word could be used.

Comment: I can't think of a sentence but I'm talking about someone who would say something like, "I don't think I'm the smartest person in the room - I know I am." and means it but at the same time is attentive and empathetic. Not self-important or an egomaniac.

Comment: But then, they *are* self-centred, by comparing themself to others in the room. "I am the smartest person" is egocentricity.

Comment: A lot of these notions are seen to be vacuous when really examined. I've just attended a funeral where I couldn't believe the number of good and exciting things this fine chap had managed to do in his life. A brilliant scientist, a fine teacher, a great administrator, a charity worker and conservationist. A loving parent. But he took the wrong grandchild home from school on one occasion. Was he as smart / responsible as the lesser lights regularly doing the school run? // That said, I don't want the best pilot on the plane saying "I'm sure we can find someone better" at 40 000 feet.

Comment: What did a thesaurus suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for the word **confident**